# How to assign a value inside an if statement and store its value forever even if you restart the program?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am creating a game in unity, its having a problem that it reset the value of a var whenever i reopen it. so,how to assign a value inside an if statement and store its value forever even if you restart the program in C#?

Comment: By saving it somewhere like a file, database, or the registry. Then you read it back on startup.

Comment: Apparently there's a thing called "PlayerPrefs" in Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: oh! let me check

Answer (score -1):

you could store the value in a database and open that database whenever you want to view or change that value. So, it would be unaffected even if you restart your program or application.[check this to save to a Microsoft SQL server](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2016/07/dotnet-save-datatable-into-database-table/)

Comment: Not advised with Unity you can simply use ```PlayerPrefs``` to save data over multiple runs no external database needed.